# Accessing information in different xml xpaths, and displaying multiple of the same paths

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new at XSLT and have some trouble extracting all the information I would like from my current example.

In the example below, I am interested in also having the message and notice text properties, and as you can see it is also repeating nodes. Can you please provide a hand at extracting this information?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><chatTranscript startAt="2016-10-06T09:16:40Z" sessionId="0001GaBYC53D000K">
    <newParty userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="1" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
        <userInfo personId="" userNick="John Doe" userType="CLIENT" protocolType="FLEX" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
        <userData>
            <item key="GMSServiceId">5954d184-f89d-4f44-8c0f-a772d458b353</item>
            <item key="IdentifyCreateContact">3</item>
            <item key="MediaType">chat</item><item key="TimeZone">120</item>
            <item key="_data_id">139-e9826bf5-c5a4-40e5-a729-2cbdb4776a43</item>
            <item key="firstName">John</item><item key="first_name">John</item>
            <item key="lastName">Doe</item>
            <item key="last_name">Doe</item>
            <item key="location_lat">37.8197</item>
            <item key="location_long">-122.4786</item>
            <item key="userDisplayName">John Doe</item>
        </userData>
    </newParty>

    <message userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="5" visibility="ALL" eventId="2">
        <msgText msgType="text" treatAs="NORMAL">This is message one.</msgText>
    </message>

    <message userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="5" visibility="ALL" eventId="2">
        <msgText msgType="text" treatAs="NORMAL">This is message two.</msgText>
    </message>

    <notice userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="246" visibility="ALL" eventId="3">
        <noticeText noticeType="USER_CUSTOM">This is notice one.</noticeText>
    </notice>

    <notice userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="246" visibility="ALL" eventId="3">
        <noticeText noticeType="USER_CUSTOM">This is notice two.</noticeText>
    </notice>

    <partyLeft userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="291" visibility="ALL" eventId="4" askerId="007957F616780001">
        <reason code="3">left due to disconnect</reason>
    </partyLeft>

</chatTranscript>
```

and xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/chatTranscript/newParty[count(*) > 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="curParty" select="@userId" />
            GMSServiceId - <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='GMSServiceId']"/>
            IdentifyCreateContact: <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='IdentifyCreateContact']"/>
            MediaType: <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='MediaType']"/>
            firstName: <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='firstName']"/>
            userDisplayName: <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='userDisplayName']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/chatTranscript/message[count(*) > 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="curParty" select="@userId" />
        Message Text: <xsl:value-of select="msgText"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The current output is:

```
GMSServiceId - 5954d184-f89d-4f44-8c0f-a772d458b353 IdentifyCreateContact: 3 MediaType: chat firstName: John userDisplayName: John Doe
```

Of course I would like to add the Message Text and Notice Text to this list.

I think what is throwing me at the moment, is the fact that the structure of the xml in the two cases are different - and I do not know how to handle the second case (used for message and notice).

Comment: Please show the exact output you expect to get in the given example.

Comment: And please could you correct the input XML? It is not [well-formed](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-wellformed) as it is missing the root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you expect to get, but it's worth noting that the template:

```
<xsl:template match="/chatTranscript/message[count(*) > 1]">
```

is not executed at all, because all the `message` elements in your example have exactly one child element. Remove the predicate, and the result will be:

```
    GMSServiceId - 5954d184-f89d-4f44-8c0f-a772d458b353
    IdentifyCreateContact: 3
    MediaType: chat
    firstName: John
    userDisplayName: John Doe
Message Text: This is message one.
Message Text: This is message two.
```

Comment: I am trying to print out the Messages and then the Notices, as in your example. How did you remove the predicate, because when I delete the <xsl:template match="/chatTranscript/message[count(*) > 1]"> line and its ending, i get an error.

Comment: @Harriet The *predicate* is the part in square brackets.

Comment: Yeah I know that - but an xml tag has a start & end tag - and when I removed both, it did not work. Don't worry I got it working though.

Comment: i am not sure what you're talking about. If you remove the `[count(*) > 1]` predicate from the match pattern above, you will get the result I show. I did not suggest removing anything else - certainly not any start or end tags.